# How to wait in node.js for a variable available on the cloud to have a specific value

Tags: node.js

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but I am trying to implement a program in node.js that should wait for the value of a variable available trough a request to a cloud api (photon.variable()) to be 1. This variable should not be requested more than once per second. My first attempt is included in the sample code below. Despite knowing  it does not work at all, I think it could be useful to show the functionality I would like to implement.

```
var photondata = 0;
while (photondata < 1)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
    photon.variable("witok", function(err, data) {
       if (!err) {
           console.log("data: ", data.result);
           photondata = data.result;
         }
       else console.log(err);
    })}, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you couldn't do async stuff in loops before, the traditional approach would be to create a function that adds itself to `setTimeout` for as long as needed, then calls some other function when it's done. You still need to do this in the browser if not using Babel.

These days, you can stop execution and wait for things to happen when using a generator function (which latest versions of Node now support). There are many libraries that will let you do this and I will advertise [ours](http://coastline.very.lv) :)

```
CL.run(function* () {

  var photondata = 0;
  while (true) {

    yield CL.try(function* () {
      var data = yield photon.variable("witok", CL.cb());
      console.log("data: ", data.result);
      photondata = data.result;
    }, function* (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });

    if (photondata >= 1) break;

    yield CL.sleep(1000);

  }

  // do whatever you need here

});
```